# Build and deploy only changed plug-ins with Tycho

Tags: java, maven, nexus, tycho

I ran into the problem that Tycho could not deploy artifacts from my multi-module project to Nexus. The reason for this was that the version already existed in Nexus and I had to enable `Allow Redeployed` for the used repository to avoid the problem.

I wonder now if there is a possibility to build only those modules whose version is not yet present in the Nexus repository.

As I am new to the topic there might also be another approach, to avoid the above described problem, which I am not aware of. Like building the single modules when they were changed instead of building the multi-module project.

#### Suggested solutions

Using SNAPSHOT versions for every plug-in is unfortunately no solution as some plug-ins are not under active development. These plug-ins cause the problem as they get rebuilt and deployed each time when the multi-module is built.

Comment: There is no way to disable the build, but Tycho can [detect that an artifact didn't change and replace it with the existing artifact](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Reproducible_Version_Qualifiers). However I don't know if this integrates with the Maven deploy plugin. If it doesn't, this could be a [new feature request](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=Tycho).

Comment: Does my answer work for your question?

Comment: Yes, it worked. I just forgot to accept the answer because moving the legacy plug-ins to another multi-module project an testing took some time. Although I have to add that mainly your comments lead me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the project is in active development (and redeploying continuosly to nexus) you must use a SNAPSHOT version. Ex 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

Your SNAPSHOTs jars will deploy againts SNAPSHOT repository with redeploy enabled.

Comment: The problem is that some plug-ins are not under active development and change rarely. Although they are rebuilt each time when the multi-module is built.

Comment: Why are they under the same project?. Are you using some CI tool ?

Comment: These plug-ins are legacy code and the new plug-ins depend on them therefore they are in the same project. They are only changed if a bug is found.
A CI tool is not used.

Comment: Put the legacy code in another project and deploy it to nexus or local repository. Then add the correct dependency to your project.